# How should I interpret the coordinates of a rectangle in PDF?

Tags: java, itextpdf

I would like to know more about the coordinates of a Rectangle,
in particular:

- lower left X
- lower left Y
- upper right X
- upper right Y

Every time, I get confused about how to make dimensions based on these coordinates to draw rectangle.

If possible, can I get a graphical representation briefly about these coordinates positions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before someone can explain what the lower-left X, lower-left Y, upper-right X and upper-right Y of a rectangle are about, you need to know about the coordinate system: [Where is the Origin (x,y) of a PDF page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319228/where-is-the-origin-x-y-of-itext-pdf-writable-area)

The answer to that question contains all the information you need, except for the graphical representation you are asking for. This is a simple representation of the coordinate system:

[image]

The origin of the coordinate system is `(0, 0)`. Positive X values are to the right of the origin, positive Y values are above the origin.

I have drawn a `Rectangle` and indicates where you can find the lower-left corner (with coordinate `(llx, lly)`) and the upper-right corner (with coordinate `(urx, ury)`).

The sides of the rectangle are always in parallel with the X and the Y axis, hence you only need two coordinates to define the rectangle.