# How to add text in PdfContentByte rectangle using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have created rectangle using PdfContentByte. Now I want to adda text inside this rectangle. How can I do this. If anybody have idea please share with me.My rectangle code is

```
 Document doc = new Document(new Rectangle(570, 924f));
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc,Response.OutputStream);
 PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
 cb.Rectangle(doc.PageSize.Width -90f, 830f, 50f,50f);
 cb.Stroke();
```

Comment: If you download the [official documentation](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) (it's free, so please do), you'll discover that your question was answered before: [How to fit a String inside a rectangle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526043/how-to-fit-a-string-inside-a-rectangle) [How can I truncate text within a bounding box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558135/how-can-i-truncate-text-within-a-bounding-box) and so on...

Comment: @ Bruno Lowagie, K let me check it once

Comment: @ Bruno Lowagie, I checked that but I didint get how to apply here?

Comment: Huh? Did you check the other examples in the documentation? I'll write you some code.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie, If I buy only I can refer the Documentation. :)

Comment: No, you can download the book for free. All you need to do, is to register.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are drawing a rectangle like this:

```
 PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
 cb.Rectangle(doc.PageSize.Width -90f, 830f, 50f,50f);
 cb.Stroke();
```

This corresponds with this `Rectangle`:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
    doc.PageSize.Width - 90f, 830f,
    doc.PageSize.Width - 40f, 880f);
```

You can add text inside this rectangle like this:

```
 ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
 ct.SetSimpleColumn(rect);
 ct.AddElement(new Paragraph("This is the text added in the rectangle"));
 ct.Go();
```

Comment: ,No overload for methode 'SetSimpleColumn' tkes 1 argument...Why?

Comment: Aha, you are using an obsolete version of iTextSharp. Make sure that you're using the latest version. The version you are using is probably several years old.

Comment: This is not always possible (at least legally), due to recent licence changes